# PIMPL: Exporting classes with single STL member (std::unique_ptr)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, unique-ptr, pimpl-idiom

Suppose I have a class `X` with private implementation `Ximpl`:

```
//Proj.h

#ifdef PROJ_EXPORTS
#define PROJ_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PROJ_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


//X.h

class PROJ_API X
{
  void foo();
  //..
private:
  class Ximpl;
  std::unique_ptr<Ximpl> x_impl;
}
```

This works perfectly, but generates the warning:

[Compiler Warning (level 1) C4251:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esew7y1w.aspx)

> warning C4251: 'X::Ximpl' : class
>   'std::unique_ptr>' needs to have
>   dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'X::Ximpl'

I have tried to follow the suggested MSDN article, but 1). it didn't work. 2) I don't clearly understand the solution(workaround)

Any advice/explanation on how to get rid of these warnings (#pragma disable's are not an option :) ).

Why is it Level 1 warning?

NOTE: It turns out that if `Ximpl` is not declared in `X` scope, then it's  possible to export a `unique_ptr<Ximpl>` after forward-declaration of `Ximpl`, but if it's in `X`s scope, then it's a nested class and therefore can't be forward-declared..

However, for templated class even above solution (have non-nested impl class), seems to fail:

```
//X.h

template<typename T>
class PROJ_API X
{
  T foo();
  //..
private:
  class Ximpl;
  std::unique_ptr<Ximpl> x_impl;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `std::unique_ptr<Ximpl> x_impl;`?

Comment: I assume there is either a direct or macro `__declspec(dllexport)` hanging out after `class` and before `X` as well; correct ?

Comment: @WhozCraig - right, edited. And declaraion/definitionss of `Ximpl` in .cpp file

Comment: Possible solution is to remove PROJ_API specifier from class X and add it to individual X methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::unique\_ptr pimpl in dll generates C4251 with visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098001/stdunique-ptr-pimpl-in-dll-generates-c4251-with-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your class X exports and declares non-inlined destructor. Otherwise the compiler implicitly declares inline destructor, which needs to know something about Ximpl in order to call its destructor. And with inline destructor, users of X also need to know how to destroy std::unique_ptr, which leads to the warning.

You can confirm this by checking that ~Ximpl() isn't called when X gets deleted, unless you export non-inlined ~X().

Comment: - Thanks for a great advice, it makes perfect sense. However, I have non-inlined constructors implemented in each class. However, it doesn't get rid of the warning if I'm not exporting (as described in MSDN article) `unique_ptr<Ximpl>`. In a template-class case, I can't even export the STL member (it's now 2-nested templates). Note, that it's possible to export instantiated template class, but not generic `X<T>`

Comment: Do you mean you have non-inlined destructors?

Comment: Yes, I meant 'destructors', not 'constructors'. However, I have both